# Return Entire Struct from Go function

Tags: json, go

I have a lengthy struct of json key value pairs returned from a GET function. Similiar to:

```
type content struct {
field1 string `json:"Language"`
field2  int `json:"Runtime"`
field3 time.Time `json:"StartTime"`
field4 time.Time `json:"EndTime"`
field5 int64 `json:"ProgramId`
field6 string `json:"ProviderId"`
field7 string `json:"Title:`
}
```

I know how to return a single field value using:

```
println(content.field1)
```

but how do I return every field name and value without listing out every element?  How would I return something like this?

```
field1:value
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281366/jsonify-map-of-structs-in-go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the JSON decoder ignores unexported field names, you must 
[export](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the field names:

```
type content struct {
  Field1 string `json:"Language"`
  Field2  int `json:"Runtime"`
  Field3 time.Time `json:"StartTime"`
  Field4 time.Time `json:"EndTime"`
  Field5 int64 `json:"ProgramId`
  Field6 string `json:"ProviderId"`
  Field7 string `json:"Title:`
}
```

To show the fields, print the decoded value `content` using "%+v":

```
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", content)
```